Issue with Pivot Table in Pandas Altering dtypes in CSV column
I have a large CSV file with a shape of (20091175, 3) formatted as follows (example of the first 3 rows):



MONTH
NIS
VALUE




APR. 2023
16167611395
771.00


APR. 2023
16122034321
600.00


APR. 2023
16121660806
750.00



The original dtypes of each column are:
MONTH:  object
NIS:    float64
VALUE:  object

I am attempting to read this CSV file and create a pivot table using the following code:

import pandas as pd

#Set display options to avoid scientific notation
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)

#Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\example_path\\example_file.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1', index_col=False, dtype={'NIS': str})

#Perform the pivot operation
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='NIS', columns='MONTH', values='VALUE')

#Save the pivoted result
df_pivot.to_csv('C:\\example_path\\pivoted_example_file.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1')

However, the resulting DataFrame alters the values in the 'NIS' column. The expected output should maintain the 'NIS' as it is in the CSV file, but it seems to be transformed somehow. Here is the altered output:



NIS
APR. 2023




10000077876
440.00


10000409143
600.00


10000559161
600.00



The 'NIS' column values are changed unexpectedly.
What could be causing this issue? Is it related to the data types or the reading process? Or maybe the file size? How can I ensure that the 'NIS' values remain exactly as they are in the original CSV file.
I have already attempted to set the dtype of the 'NIS' column to str in the pd.read_csv command because I suspected the issue might arise from the column being read as float64.
The expected output should maintain the 'NIS' as it is in the CSV file, like this:



NIS
APR. 2023




16167611395
771.00


16122034321
600.00


16121660806
750.00



Thank you for your help!

My guess, as far as I remember: the index of the pivoted dataframe gets sorted. You can easily check that by looking at the sorted (along NIS) original dataframe.
